# removeClass nao funciona

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Preciso validar dois campos em meu form para entao habilitar o botao de Submit para o usuario final, porem o `removeClass('disabled')` nao esta funcionando.

```
    $('#main-form').on(function () {
        simCode = $('#main-form [name=code]').val().length;
        carrierId = $('#main-form [name=carrierId]').val();

        if (simCode == 20 || carrierId != "null") {
           $('#save').removeClass('disabled');
        }
    });
```

Lembrando que `simCode` recebe os valores de um input type text e `carrierId` recebe o valor de um select option

Comment: Não seria `.removeProp`?

Comment: Ele pode ter uma classe `.disabled`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O `disabled` não é uma classe, é uma propriedade.

Use:

```
$('#save').prop('disabled', true);
```

**Exemplo:**

```js
function desabilita(){
  $('#save').prop('disabled', true);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="desabilita()">Clique aqui para desabilitar o botão abaixo</a>
<br>
<button type="button" id="save">Botão</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Você não incluiu o seu html, mas ao que tudo indica o `disabled` que se refere não é uma classe de estilo e sim um atributo do elemento.

```
$('#main-form').on(function () {
    simCode = $('#main-form [name=code]').val().length;
    carrierId = $('#main-form [name=carrierId]').val();

    if (simCode == 20 || carrierId != "null") {
       $('#save').attr('disabled', false);
    }
});
```